# GeoServer and PostGIS connection technology?

Tags: postgis, geoserver

Does anybody know how GeoServer connects to PostGIS. Which technology is used? Is it JDBC?

Comment: If this is "too localized" then why we keep all those ArcObjects questions which are more localized?

Comment: @R.K. Sorry? ...

Comment: Ah my bad. Somebody voted to close this thread. I was reacting to that.

Comment: yes jdbc is used

Comment: @R.K. - we should probably vote to close those too, in fact we should close any question where googling two or the three key words from the question answers it.

Comment: Yeah. We probably should. Far too many of them, though. Oh well, better start now. :)

Comment: Well ... Could you show me what keywords you typed in Google to obtain the information I'm looking for on the first page?

Comment: using: "GeoServer connects to PostGIS". Second link : 
Using JNDI¶. GeoServer can also connect to a PostGIS database using JNDI ( Java Naming and Directory Interface).  (geoserver 2.2 documentation) . This is not that bad question.